# Why does only one JavaScript function execute onClick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I'm sort of new to JavaScript, that being said I've encountered a weird error in my code. I have three images in my HTML that when clicked should open in a modal. For some reason the modal will get stuck on the last of the new images. For example if I click on the first, then the third then the second, no matter what image I click on the second displays. I tried debugging by replacing the the a H1 tag with the name of the image, which threw another curve because now it takes two clicks to execute the modal. I am not sure what I doing and any help is appreciated.

JS-

```
<script>
function mode(param)
{

    smode = param;
    document.getElementById("h1thing").innerHTML = smode;
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = smode;
    run();

}
function run(){
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');


// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById(smode);

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";

}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    smode = "";

}



// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        smode = "";
    }
}
}
</script>
```

HTML-

```
<body>

<h2 id="h1thing">Modal Example</h2>


<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<center>
<div class="floated_img">
    <input id="ScreenShot.png" type="image" src="ScreenShot.png" width="400" height="300" alt="ScreenShot" onclick="myFunction();mode('ScreenShot.png');">
    </input>
</div>
<div class="floated_img">
    <input id="ScreenShot2.png" type="image" src="ScreenShot2.png" width="400" height="300" alt="ScreenShot2" onclick="myFunction();mode('ScreenShot2.png');">
    </input>
</div>
<div class="floated_img">
    <input id="kimlexi.jpg" type="image" src="kimlexi.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="Kimlexi" onclick="myFunction();mode('kimlexi.jpg');">
    </input>
</div>
</center>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">

            <img src="x.png" width="40" height="40" alt="X">
    </span>
    <center>
        <img id="myImage" src="" width="600" height="500" alt="Kimlexi">
    </center>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
```

CSS-

```
<style>
button {
    background:transparent;
      border:none;
      outline:none;
      display:block;
      height:200px;
      width:200px;
      cursor:pointer;
}
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.floated_img
{
    float: left;
}
</style>
```

Comment: what is "myFunction()?

Comment: Opps! I forgot to take that out it was a simple dialog I used during some debugging process that would print the name of the file.

Comment: @NicholasGenco you should learn to use `console.log`. It's the proper way to debug stuff like this. You shouldn't have to print stuff to the DOM to see what they are

Comment: Noted. I will try that.

Comment: You might want to take a look at bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Comment: Tip: `:target` selector also works for simple modals. (Also has good browser support and doesn't rely on JS.)

Comment: And don't use `<center>` it doesn't exist in HTML5. Use CSS.

Comment: `smode` is declared in `mode()`, i.e in another scope, invisible in `run()` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem

There are two problems here.

1. **The first button click does not open the modal.** The first time you click the image (let's use the first image as an example), the `mode('ScreenShot.png')` is executed, which

   1. sets smode to 'ScreenShot.png'
   2. shows smode (='ScreenShot.png') in the `<h1>`
   3. sets smode (='ScreenShot.png') as the `<img>`'s `src`
   4. calls run(), which changes the `onclick` handler for the button but never actually opens the modal!
2. **The second click on the same button might show the wrong image.** This happens because the button's `onclick` handler was overwritten in step 1.4 above (it is overwritten, not added), and the new event handler (`btn.onclick = function() { modal.style.display = "block"; }`) only makes the modal visible but does not change the image source.

### Suggested solution

It will be easier if you only set the `onclick` handler once. Here is one solution.

JS-

```
function openModal(imgSrc)
{
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = imgSrc;
    document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
    document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == document.getElementById('myModal')) {
        closeModal();
    }
}
```

HTML-

```
<input type="image" src="….png" width="400" height="300" 
        alt="ScreenShot" onclick="openModal('….png');">
…
<span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">
```

Comment: Thank you! As soon as I get home I'll check this out but appreciate everyone's guidance! Thank you all!